# How to collect answer from dynamically created form using vaadin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I am developing a Survey Collection web application using `vaadin` flow 23 and I made the survey forms to be built dynamically using data from the database the create question method is called until all rows of the questions are completed and I want to get the user response from the form, But I don't know how to achieve that using `vaadin` please help.

```
public class CreateSurvey extends VerticalLayout{
TextField title = new TextField("Title");
TextField preamble = new TextField("Preamble");
TextField description = new TextField("Description");
TextField category = new TextField("Category");
SurveyService surveyService;
QuestionService questionService;
Button submit = new Button("Submit");
public CreateSurvey(SurveyService surveyService,QuestionService questionService) {
    this.surveyService = surveyService;
    this.questionService=questionService;


    Survey survey = surveyService.findSurvey(1L);
    title.setValue(survey.getTitle());
    title.setReadOnly(true);
    preamble.setValue(survey.getPreamble());
    preamble.setReadOnly(true);
    description.setValue(survey.getDescription());
    description.setReadOnly(true);
    category.setValue(survey.getCategory().toString());
    category.setReadOnly(true);
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();
    layout.add(title,preamble,description,category);
    layout.setResponsiveSteps(new FormLayout.ResponsiveStep("0",1));


    add(layout);

    for(Question question: questionService.findQuestion(survey.getId())){
        add(createQuestionRow(question));
    }

    getChildren().forEach(component->{
        System.out.println(component.getElement().toString());
    });
    submit.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
        
    });

}


private Component createQuestionRow(Question question) {
    FormLayout layout =new FormLayout();
    List<String>  answers = new ArrayList<>();
    H5 qOrder = new H5(String.valueOf(question.getQuestionOrder()));
    H6 statement = new H6(question.getStatement());
    HorizontalLayout statementLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    statementLayout.add(qOrder,statement);
    statementLayout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);
    RadioButtonGroup<String> optionsRadio = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
    TextField shortAnswer = new TextField();
    List<String> list;
    Checkbox required = new Checkbox("Is Required");
    required.setValue(question.isRequired());
    required.isReadOnly();
    VerticalLayout options = new VerticalLayout();
    if(question.getOption()== Option.linearTen){
        optionsRadio.setItems("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
        options.add(optionsRadio);
    }
    else if (question.getOption()== Option.AnnotatedFour) {
        optionsRadio.setItems("Excellent","Very good","good","bad");
        options.add(optionsRadio);
    }
    else if ( question.getOption()==Option.shortAnswer){
        options.add(shortAnswer);
    }
    optionsRadio.addValueChangeListener(click->{
     answers.add(click.getValue());
        System.out.println(click.getValue());
    });

    layout.add(statementLayout,options,required);
    layout.setResponsiveSteps(new FormLayout.ResponsiveStep("0",2));
    layout.setColspan(statementLayout,2);
    return layout;

}
```

}

[image: look the radiobuttongroup]

Comment: What have you tried?  What is not working?  Basically all fields
implement `HasValue`.  You most likely want to add some book keeping
(what field was created for which question) and when the user submits,
you ask all those fields for their value.

Comment: I tried to get the component from the `FormLayout` but components doesn't possess `getValue()` method. Basically I wanted to get the selected item value and its position. to make up the answer.

Comment: Component containers like FormLayout are meant to be used for you to "remember" fields (just to show them). Track your fields for yourself (e.g. put them in a list or a map)

Comment: Thank you you gave me a useful insight I will try adding them to a list.

Comment: edit: **not** meant to remember...

Comment: Check the data binding documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need some kind of data structure to store your answers. You can put them in the `Question` class or just use an array of `String`s, but probably it makes sense to use a dedicated class, such as:

```java
public class Answer {
    String value;
    Question question;
    public Answer(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Note that you might eventually want to expand into more specialized answer classes like `NumericalAnswer` or `TextualAnswer` but let's keep things simple in the beginning.

You can initialize each `Question`'s answer in the beginning of `createQuestionRow` like this:

```java
    private Component createQuestionRow(Question question) {
        FormLayout layout =new FormLayout();
        Answer answer = new Answer(question);
        // ...
```

Next, you'll need to create a `Binder`, which is a helper class that allows connecting fields (like `TextField`) to data classes (like `Answer`). `Binder` uses a generic type to specify the data it reads and writes from; in this case we'll use `Answer`. So continuing in `createQuestionRow`:

```java
        Binder<Answer> binder = new Binder<>();
```

Binder allows you to write values to the bean (Answer) either immediately or only after being programmatically instructed to do so. You want to write values when the Submit button is pressed, so we'll need the latter. This means we need access to the `Binder` outside of the method, so let's create a List of Binders. We'll also create a Map to keep track of which Binder corresponds to which Answer. Add the two declarations in the beginning of the CreateSurvey class:

```java
public class CreateSurvey extends VerticalLayout {
    // List of all Binders used
    List<Binder<Answer>> binders = new ArrayList<>();
    // Map of Binder to Answer
    Map<Binder<Answer>, Answer> answers = new HashMap<>();
```

Now let's populate the `binders` List and the `answers` Map in `createQuestionRow`:

```java
        binders.add(binder);
        answers.put(binder, answer);
```

Next, let's configure the Binder to connect the input fields and tell Binder how it should read and write the values:

```java
        if(question.getOption()== Option.linearTen){
            optionsRadio.setItems("10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1");
            options.add(optionsRadio);
            // new
            binder.forField(optionsRadio).bind(Answer::getValue, Answer::setValue);
        }
        else if (question.getOption()== Option.AnnotatedFour) {
            optionsRadio.setItems("Excellent","Very good","good","bad");
            options.add(optionsRadio);
            // new
            binder.forField(optionsRadio).bind(Answer::getValue, Answer::setValue);
        }
        else if ( question.getOption()==Option.shortAnswer){
            options.add(shortAnswer);
            // new
            binder.forField(shortAnswer).bind(Answer::getValue, Answer::setValue);
        }
```

Finally, we need to tell the Binders to write out their values when the Submit button is clicked. At the end of the constructor:

```java
       submit.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            for (Binder<Answer> binder : binders) {
                Answer answer = answers.get(binder);
                try {
                    binder.writeBean(answer);
                    // Print out the answers to System.out
                    System.out.println("Answer to question " + answer.getQuestion().getStatement() + ": " + answer.getValue());
                } catch (ValidationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Validation failed: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

This still leaves you a couple of things to sort out, such as how to actually make the `isRequired` questions required, but it should be enough to get you started.